# Robolectric packagemanager doesn't return correct value for getNameForUid?

Tags: robolectric, android-package-managers

I keep getting null, even though the package is added. I looked at the source, turns out StubPackageManager is always returning null for that and there is no way to override the entire PackageManager class.

Answer (score 1):

In setup:

```
MockPackageManager mockPackageManager = new MockPackageManager(
    Robolectric.getShadowsAdapter());
RuntimeEnvironment.setRobolectricPackageManager(mockPackageManager);
```

Subclass:

```
class MockPackageManager extends DefaultPackageManager {

  public MockPackageManager(ShadowsAdapter shadowsAdapter) {
    super(shadowsAdapter);
  }

  @Override
  public String getNameForUid(int uid) {
    switch (uid) {
      case UID_A:
        return NAME_A;
      case UID_B:
        return NAME_B;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isPermissionRevokedByPolicy(String s, String s1) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Can you also create an issue on the Robolectric github?